# Reset object rotation

Tags: transforms

My object has been rotated randomly for some reason on all axis. When I import it into Unity the rotation still applies. How can I reset it so it's the right way up?

Comment: Depending on the case, you can reset rotation or apply rotation. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: I tried doing this but there is no values to reset. It's like it forgot it was rotated at some point.

Comment: Was the object rotated in Edit mode ?

Comment: I think so, I had some trouble with the camera and for some reason the object ended up rotated badly.

Comment: Also please clarify what the trouble did you have with camera. If it means that it is the camera rotated then it's a simple matter of resetting / cleaning that rotation and scene meshes have nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rotation which was done in Edit mode can't be reset as it would be possible with rotation in Object mode. Depending on the case, it's possible to use workaround.

1. Create an empty. While still in Object mode, enable [Snap During Transform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#transform-snapping) and choose *Snap to Face* as type of element. Enable [*Align Rotation With the Snapping Target*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#additional-snap-options) button.
2. Grab empty, hovering the mouse over faces which should be rotated along world axes. I.e. in case of building this will be faces representing the floor.
3. Once empty is snapped, it gained new rotation values. [Parent](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html) object to the empty with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
4. Select empty and clear its rotation transforms (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). Object will follow changed rotation and should become aligned along world axes (or at least roughly aligned).
5. [Clear Parent](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/parent.html#clear-parent) with (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) by selecting Clear and Keep Transformation.
6. Select empty, then delete with <kbd>X</kbd>.

[image: GIF resetting rotation done in Edit mode]

Comment: The links you posted are broken now, could you please update in the description how to do these operations?

Comment: What is the part you do that highlights the box in blue?  I am still not getting it 100%.  It would help if I could pause the video.

Comment: @Jonathan yes, most links to manual are being rebuilt quite constantly (and broken). I edited them for now given the version I was writiting the answer for. I'd suggest looking in google queries from the link description when you face similar case. For your second question, I clicked the object to select it; it was blue highlight in that UI theme. As there's only gif image here unfortunately no way to pause it unless installing an addon for the browser; there are keyboard shortcuts shown in the bottom left, maybe they could help